# Issues with SfDateRangePicker and bottom_sheet widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I get an error in my flutter log when trying to use `SfDateRangePicker` in release mode with `modal_bottom_sheet` or any other `bottom_sheet` widget.
this is the error text
"Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty' "

```dart
          Future<void> dIALOG2() {
    TextTheme _textthem = Theme
        .of(context)
        .textTheme;
    ColorScheme COLOR = Theme
        .of(context)
        .colorScheme;
    var w = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .width;
    var h = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .height;
    return showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        elevation: 0,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return FractionallySizedBox(
              heightFactor: h / 950,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: w / 2,
                            height: h / 20,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: h / 50),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Center(
                                  child: Text('Bubble Duration:',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      style: _textthem.headlineLarge!.copyWith(
                                          fontFamily: 'Red Hat Display',
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          letterSpacing: 0.4,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          height: 1)),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Text(""),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const Text(""),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: const Color(0xff942657),
                    width: w,
                    height: h / 180,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: w / 1.2,
                    height: h / 1.5,
                    child: SfDateRangePicker(
                      monthCellStyle: DateRangePickerMonthCellStyle(
                        textStyle: _textthem.headline1!.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            letterSpacing: 0.2199999988079071,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            height: 1.5714285714285714),
                        disabledDatesTextStyle: _textthem.headline1!.copyWith(
                            color: const Color.fromRGBO(96, 96, 96, 1),
                            fontSize: 14,
                            letterSpacing: 0.2199999988079071,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            height: 1.5714285714285714),
                      ),
                      controller: _pickerController,
                      showNavigationArrow: true,
                      toggleDaySelection: true,
                      rangeSelectionColor: const Color(0xffCF6D38),
                      endRangeSelectionColor: const Color(0xffA83063),
                      onSelectionChanged: _onSelectionChanged2,
                      startRangeSelectionColor: const Color(0xffA83063),
                      view: DateRangePickerView.month,
                      selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      if (STartTime == "" || EndTime == "") {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      } else if (STartTime != "" && EndTime != "") {
                        _OptionsBloc.add(
                            ChangeDone1((b) => b..DoneColor1 = true));
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: w / 2,
                      height: h / 16,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(7),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(7),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(7),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(7),
                        ),
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(148, 38, 87, 1),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Confirm',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: _textthem.headline1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                ],
              )

          );
        }
    );
  }
```

Comment: It would help if you copied and pasted the entire error message text from your log here.

Comment: Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'

Comment: this is the error i get in release mode

Comment: ok its fine now you can check it out

Comment: If I get you clearly, the error is in release mode (flutter build), like you don't experience it when coding with "flutter run", right?

Comment: yes only in Release mode it works fine with flutter run

Comment: i used showMaterialModalBottomSheet Model sheet package and it worked fine